What is the error on the weighted mean?
I am combining bins in the histogram. I have some code that uses this formula to calculate the error on the weighted mean:
$$\sigma = \frac{\sqrt{\sum \frac{w_{i}(w_{i}\sigma_{i}^{2}+x_{i}^{2})}{\sum w_{i}}-(\frac{\sum w_{i}x_{i}}{\sum w_{i}})^{2}}}{\sqrt{\sum w_{i}}}$$
Can somebody show me how this is derived? Where can I find more info about this formula?
